# Como inserir fotos de uma pasta em uma célula no Excel automaticamente?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu necessito inserir diversas imagens no Excel, porem está difícil ficar inserindo de uma a uma, são mais de 300 fotos, e haverá atualizações dessas fotos.

Eu queria saber se há uma maneira de realizar tal procedimento?

Answer (score 1):

Abra o Excel, e pressione <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, irá abrir o VBE (Visual Basic Editor). Como botão direito do mouse clique sobre "VBAProject" e escolha "Inserir > Módulo":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Insira o código abaixo na janela (veja os comentários):

```
Option Explicit

Sub Insert()

    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim objPic As Picture
    Dim rngCell As Range

    strFolder = "D:\pasta_com_as_imagens\" 'altere o caminho para onde estão as imagens
    If Right(strFolder, 1) <> "\" Then
        strFolder = strFolder & "\"
    End If

    Set rngCell = Range("E1") 'célula de início

    strFileName = Dir(strFolder & "*.jpg", vbNormal) 'arquivos jpg

    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        Set objPic = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(strFolder & strFileName)
        With objPic
            .Left = rngCell.Left
            .Top = rngCell.Top
            .Height = rngCell.RowHeight
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        Set rngCell = rngCell.Offset(1, 0)
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Pressione <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> para salvar o código e escolha a opção em "Tipo" como mostrado na figura abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Feche a janela do VBE.

No Excel, pressione <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> e clique em "Executar":

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso irá inserir todas as imagens da pasta indicada no código linha por linha da planilha.

Comment: Didático e imagens +1